# <no location info>: error: can't find file

Tags: macos, file, haskell, filesystems, file-attributes

I am using haskell version 8.2.2 on a mac and currently have a problem to compile a file :

My terminal:

```
$ls 
try.hs 
$ ghc -o try try.hs
<no location info>: error: can't find file: try.hs
```

Terminal after `ls -l` :

```
total 0 
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 <>  <> 0 Mar 23 15:54 try.hs
```

Terminal after `ls -l@` :

```
total 0
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 <>  <>  0 Mar 23 15:54 try.hs 
com.apple.TextEncoding  15 
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags 42 
com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_z4p7jqbpj7dblx5lt33gtc742u  105
```

Comment: What do you get if you just use `ghc try.hs`?  ghc isn't gcc. It names the binary based on the input file by default.

Comment: unfortunately same error

Comment: Unfortunately NOT same error. For me, with ghc 8.0.2 on Ubuntu 17.10, using the -o flag like this works just fine.

Comment: What are the permissions on `try.hs`? What is the contents of `try.hs`? What are the permissions on the current directory?

Comment: Hm, tried with ghc 8.2.2 in Ubuntu 17.10 and that also works perfectly. Can you do "ls -l" (that is a lower case L)

Comment: the file is empty, permissions are read and write

Comment: There are many circumstances where `ls` would *appear* to show the existence of a file named `try.hs` when the file was actually named something else.  What happens if you try `cat try.hs`?  Does it find the file?

Comment: @hhwwww And the permissions on the current directory? Bonus points for pasting the output of `ls -ld . try.hs`, so that we don't have to guess exactly what your vague "permissions are read and write" means.

Comment: @hhwwww After typing up two or three different replies, I can only conclude that I don't know what you mean. I can't think of any sensible interpretation of "filetype was a text-edit document and now it isn't" that would affect whether GHC considered that file to exist or not. Whether the file name includes ".hs" or not is a red herring; names are just names, and can be whatever the heck you like, so long as the program you're using on the file likes it as well as you do.

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for ur time, i found the issue with ur help so it wasn't wasted :) the filetype was a text-edit document. Now I created a new one ...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have symlink'd a non-existent file to `try.hs`. Here is a sample of how things look in my test directory where I can see the same error as you:

```
% ls try.hs
try.hs
% ghc try.hs
<no location info>: error: can't find file: try.hs
% ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 <redacted> <redacted> 5 Mar 23 10:57 try.hs -> wrong
```

As you can see by the `l` at the beginning of the permissions and the `-> wrong` after the file name, here `try.hs` is a symlink to `wrong`. But there is no file named `wrong`.